# Use JQuery Ajax Load on a Div Loaded by another Ajax Load

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a `div` in my `db_sample_ajax.php`,

```
<div class="form_header" id="form_header">

</div>
```

using the jQuery code,

```
$("#form_header").load('ajax/ajax_form_header.php', {"memid":hidden_value} );
```

I have loaded the div class "form_header" with labels and inputs plus a div

```
<div class="divMunicipality" id="divMunicipality" name="divMunicipality">New Div </div>
```

I'm encountering a problem when I call another JQuery Ajax Load to the div class "divMunicipality" using the code below:

```
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        $("#txtAddress").focusout(function(){
            var barangay2 = $(this).val();  
            alert(barangay2);   
            $("#divMunicipality").load('ajax/ajax_divmunicipality.php', {"barangay1":barangay2} );
        });             
    });
```

The alert part of the code is working.
If I replace the `div class="divMunicipality"` with other `div` class in my `db_sample_ajax.php` code, It's working properly.

Comment: I just tested on my local machine and it worked for me (I created new files and copy pasted your code) so I would double check spelling on "ajax/ajax_divmunicipality.php" to make sure it exists. You can check the network tab of your browsers developer tools to see what the response of the ajax call is. Also could you explain more what you mean by "If I replace the div class="divMunicipality" with other div class in my db_sample_ajax.php code, It's working properly."?

Comment: @MrMadsen, what I mean by replacing the div class="divMunicipality" is that I simply added a new div class in my "db_sample_ajax.php". When I use that new div as to where my ajax would load, my code works...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $(document).on("focusout", "#txtAddress", function(){
        var barangay2 = $(this).val();
        alert(barangay2);
        $("#divMunicipality").load('ajax/ajax_divmunicipality.php', {"barangay1":barangay2} );
 });
```

Comment: don't forget to remove the .ajaxComplete() method